# Finding roots by Fixed Point Iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

How to know or how to find the root of the equation by Fixed Point Iteration? In FPI is there any definition/theorem of when root exists? Or is it correct that when `x = g(x)` then `x` is the root of an equation ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you be more precise about what the question is?  More specifically, what is confusing to you about the exposition that you've read?  It seems like some of the more basic parts of your question can be found on Wikipedia, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem called [Banach Fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) which proves the convergence of a fixed point iteration.

*Definition.* Let (X, d) be a metric space. Then a map T : X → X is called a contraction mapping on X if there exists q ∈ [0, 1) such that

> $d(T(x),T(y)) \le q d(x,y)$

for all x, y in X.

**Banach Fixed Point Theorem.** Let (X, d) be a non-empty complete metric space with a contraction mapping T : X → X. Then T admits a unique fixed-point x* in X $(i.e. T(x^*) = x^*)$. Furthermore, x* can be found as follows: start with an arbitrary element $x_0$ in X and define a sequence $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ by $x_n = T(x_n−1)$, then $x_n → x^*$.

One of the big challenges is to actually find a map  T : X → X that satisfies this criteria. For 1D systems, Newton's method satisfies only for a small section of the real-line. It is for this reason you need to start very close to the solution to get to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer. Sometimes there are intuitive transformations that give a good fixed point method, like transforming $0=x^5-x^2-1$ to
$$
x=g(x)=\sqrt[5]{1+x^2}
$$

Sometimes you have to follow general schemes like the Newton method. But even that does not give a unique fixed point method and even the Newton methods for equivalent formulations of the problem need not have similar qualities (except for the extremely local quadratic convergence).

For instance, for the square root problem, the Newton methods starting from
$$
f(x)=x^2-a,\ f(x)=x^{3/2}-ax^{-1/2},\ f(x)=1-ax^{-2}
$$
give very different fixed point iterations.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it correct that when $x = g(x)$ then $x$ is the root of an equation
>   ?

When $x = g(x)$, $x$ is the root of the function $f(x):= g(x) - x$.

As other answers have noted, sometimes you will want to use a more complicated transformation to ensure that your fixed point iteration actually converges. Specific advice is hard to give without context. But a fixed point can easily be converted to a root by subtraction.